# window.location.reload is refreshing page again and again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am working on project where I am invalidating browser cache but when I call this function `window.location.reload()` it refresh page again and again . I want to reload page at once . Could someone please help me how to stop page from refreshing again and again .  Thanks

**Note:** I am using React.JS

**Code**

```
import React from "react";
import packageJson from "../package.json";
global.appVersion = packageJson.version;

// version from response - first param, local version second param
const semverGreaterThan = (versionA, versionB) => {
  const versionsA = versionA.split(/\./g);

  const versionsB = versionB.split(/\./g);
  while (versionsA.length || versionsB.length) {
    const a = Number(versionsA.shift());

    const b = Number(versionsB.shift());
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-continue
    if (a === b) continue;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
    return a > b || isNaN(b);
  }
  return false;
};

class CacheBuster extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      isLatestVersion: false,
      refreshCacheAndReload: (caches) => {
        if (caches) {
          caches.keys().then(async function (names) {
            await Promise.all(names.map((name) => caches.delete(name)));
          });
        }

        window.location.reload();
      },
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/meta.json?${new Date().getTime()}`, { cache: "no-cache" })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((meta) => {
        const latestVersion = meta.version;
        const currentVersion = global.appVersion;

        const shouldForceRefresh = semverGreaterThan(
          latestVersion,
          currentVersion
        );
        if (shouldForceRefresh) {
          console.log(
            `We have a new version - ${latestVersion}. Should force refresh`
          );
          this.setState({ loading: false, isLatestVersion: false });
        } else {
          console.log(
            `You already have the latest version - ${latestVersion}. No cache refresh needed.`
          );
          this.setState({ loading: false, isLatestVersion: true });
        }
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { loading, isLatestVersion, refreshCacheAndReload } = this.state;
    return this.props.children({
      loading,
      isLatestVersion,
      refreshCacheAndReload,
    });
  }
}

export default CacheBuster;
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in this code. You could be calling this function again each time the page loads.

Comment: I would also move the reload immediately below the "await" line.

Comment: @Heroselohim . Well, I am following this tutorial for cache busting . Could you please check this link . I moved it above but don't know it will be work as I want or not 
https://dev.to/flexdinesh/cache-busting-a-react-app-22lk

Comment: @Heroselohim I just updated my question could you please check !

Comment: Did my provided solution work? And if so, could you mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (caches) {...} else (window.location.reload(true));
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This code is struck between constructor and the render. 
this.state.refreshCacheAndReload should be set to null in constructor, where in you choose to reload it in componentdidmount whenever the version mismatches.